# Can I upgrade my Acer One Happy2 notebook to 4 GB

Tags: netbook, acer-aspire-one

I have an Acer Aspire One Happy2 netbook with 2GB of ram.

Can I upgrade memory on this netbook to 4 GB?

Also want to know how many memory slot does it have?

Comment: I think I found the answer. Atom N570 that comes with the Acer One Happy2 can only support max 2GB of ram. 

Reference:
http://ark.intel.com/products/55637/Intel-Atom-Processor-N570-%281M-Cache-1_66-GHz%29

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to the [product page on Acer's site](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/LU.SG00D.023).  It looks like they have a few different models available.  I couldn't find a max RAM size, but every one that I clicked into only had one memory slot.